# Question related to probability and law of total probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I was doing some exercises related to probability in the textbook and I got stuck on this question. My answer is $5.5\%$ but the answer of the textbook is $6\%$ I'm not sure if it's correct.

> The fruit shop bought $10$ boxes of apples from $3$ different orchards. $3$ boxes from the *northern* garden, $5$ boxes from the *central* garden, and $2$ boxes from the *southern* garden.  In these $3$ orchards, the probability of an apple being spotted is $10\%$, $3\%$, and $5\%$, respectively.  Assuming that the number of apples in different boxes is equal, what is the probability that the apple we pick up from one of the boxes is spotted?

I would be happy if you help me find the right answer.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello!! What have you tried to address the problem?

Comment: Your answer is correct. The book seems to have just taken the simple average which is incorrect.